# Using PostgreSQL NOTIFY payload in QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis, refresh

I am using the NOTIFY signal of PostgreSQL intensively to update a PostGIS-layer in the map (see https://oslandia.com/en/2017/10/07/refresh-your-maps-from-postgresql/).

Additionally to the channel 'qgis', I am sending a payload with the latitude and longitude of the newly added point.

Now, additionally to the update of the layer, I would like to pan the map automatically to the location given in the payload of the NOTIFY signal.

Question:

- How can I reuse the NOTIFY payload of the qgis-channel of PostgreSQL in QGIS (e.g. within a Python-based layer-action).

Looking for any hints.

Answer (score 1):

As per this PR (https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/commit/02e3916bf59a67abc81a8c90a3e246a5984f5c3), it should be simple as subscribing to notify signal at corresponding QgsDataProvider (https://qgis.org/api/classQgsDataProvider.html#abdb764c89cc99ccaa418178c26d84c32)